# x86 MASM Assembly - Empty Variable that Holds a String

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Below is what I declared as a variable to hold a string.

```
tempStr BYTE 30 DUP(?)
```

I would store a string of numbers and it would output normally. But if I store it again with a shorter string, it would include parts of what I included when I first stored it. An example is below:

Input 1 for tempStr: 57894

Output 1: 57894

Input 2 for tempStr: 137

Output 2: 13794

```
mov edx, OFFSET tempStr
mov ecx, (SIZEOF tempStr) - 1
call ReadString
etc
```

Is there an easy way to fix this issue like clearing all the contents of the string variable?

Edit: This is solved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What determines the length of the string?

Comment: tempStr BYTE 30 DUP(?). The length and size are both 30.

Comment: That's the size of the buffer. I think @RossRidge meant the length of the string that you store in the buffer. That is, does `ReadString` place a NUL-terminator (or some other string terminator) after the characters that have been read? And does the function that you use to output the strings use the same kind of string terminator?

Comment: Yah, if the length of the string is actually 30 characters then it should be printing 30 characters, not 5. Either you're not showing the extra 25 characters in your example output, or the length is actually 5. If it's the former you need someway to set the length something other than 30, either a variable or end of string terminator. If it's the later then you're either not setting the length correctly or your functions aren't agreeing on how strings are terminated like Michael suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If ReadString does not ZERO-terminate the string, you have to clear it before with zeroes, e.g.

```
cld             ; clear direction flag for REP = count up
lea edi, tempStr
mov ecx, (SIZEOF tempStr)
mov al, 0
rep stosb       ; repeats a put-byte of AL ECX times starting from address EDI
```

Comment: I tried many ways to clear out the string with zeros and it appears that what you gave me works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be nice if you'd accept the answer.